# Excel VBA index match a csv import

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, csv

How can I use an index match function in VBA to find values in a CSV file then import those values to the matched index in a cell in Excel? Say I have a CSV file which contains the following comma deliminated text:

lookup1, 2

lookup2, 3

And the following data in Sheet2 in Excel:

B2 = lookup1

C2 = 0

B3 = lookup2

C3 = 0

How do I use an index match to find the value 2 in the second column for "lookup1" in the CSV file and then change the value to 2 in cell C2 in Excel?

I've tried the code below but it doesn't work and I don't think it's looking in the Excel sheet to match where the value needs to go

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim arr1

    arr1 = CsvToArray(Application.GetOpenFilename)

    Debug.Print TestLookup(arr1, "lookup1", 1, 2)

End Sub

Function TestLookup(arr, val, lookincol As Integer, returnfromcol As Integer)
    Dim r
    r = Application.Match(val, Application.Index(arr, 0, lookincol), 0)
    If Not IsError(r) Then
        TestLookup = arr(r, returnfromcol)
    Else
        TestLookup = "Not found" 'or some other "error" value
    End If
End Function

Function CsvToArray(filepath As String) As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    CsvToArray = wb.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").CurrentRegion.Value
End Function
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Index` and `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` in VBA, but I doubt it will be useful in this case.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad i made changes to the post to include the code I've used so far, but it's not quite what i need

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV file needs to be formatted with a proper header.

In plain text it would look like:

```
lookup1,lookup2
2,3
```

Would comment but not ranked high enough yet.